# Android Cordova2.3 -jquery ajax($.support.cors = true) not working(same request works on chrome browser)

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have read about this issue and have tried every possible solution online but nothing worked..
Here is my html code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script>

$( document ).bind( "mobileinit", function() {
    // Make your jQuery Mobile framework configuration changes here!
    console.log("made cors changes");
    //$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = true;
    $.support.cors = true;
    $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;

});
</script>
<script src="cordova-2.3.0.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header" data-position="fixed" >
        <h4>
            JLT
        </h4>

    </div>
    <div data-role="content" >

        <p>
        Send data to server?
        </p>
        <a data-role="button" id="transportYES" data-inline="true">
            Yes
        </a>
        <a data-role="button" id="transportNO" data-inline="true">
            No
        </a>


    </div>
</div>


<script>

$( "#transportYES" ).bind( "click", function(event, ui) {
  console.log('clicked');


    $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "http://api.wordnik.com//v4/word.json/recant/definitions",
   data: "includeRelated=false&includeTags=false&useCanonical=false&api_key=7741b711eec09c12e05070046d60da6b92e03750359859fde",
   dataType: "json",
   beforeSend:function(){
   console.log('before sending');
   },
   success: function(msg){
     alert( msg[0].word );
   },
   error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
   console.log(xhr);

     alert( 'error' );
   }
 });


});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If i run this code from chrome i get the response from the server, but when packaged with phonegap it doesnt work from the android emulator..
I have even allowed all domain as follows  `<access origin=".*"/>` in the config.xml file..
Have been stuck on this issue for a long time..please help..!!!!

It works on the device the problem was on the emulator.....couldn't get hold of a testing device earlier.. could have saved so much time...... :)

Comment: Keep in mind, that this access-origin-whitelist does not apply to stuff done via the inAppBrowser-plugin. Whitelisting will only work in the main Cordova webview!

Answer (score 0):

Your mobileinit event  work work unless you put this code in a file between jQuery and jQuery Mobile.

You have to do as below(just an example)

```
<script src="js/external/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/configs.js"></script>
<script src="js/external/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>
```

Inside your configs.js just place your mobileinit

```
$( document ).bind( "mobileinit", function() {
   //your code
});
```

Comment: Hi rodrigo thanks for your reply..as you have seen in my code i have already specified the script between both the jquery files..and it even gets called as i have tested it..but as per your suggestion i even put it into an external js file..but still get the same result.   xhr.status as '0' in the error block..

Comment: hum so the problem is the request, right? try removing that extra "/" in the api url before v4 and so on

Comment: the request is fine..the above code works perfectly in chrome..thats what confuses me..i have no idea what else i can try..

Comment: the js files are not in a folder? Are they in the same folder as index.html?

Comment: yes..all the files are in the proper location..and loaded properly..the issue is something else..not sure what :(

Comment: check the api log and see if the request appears